# Stored procedures allow names of non-existing tables in definition

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

Why stored procedures allow to reference non-existing table names in definition? This is not allowed for table columns, only for tables.

Example:

This code you can execute, and stored procedure will be created.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Test
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM dbo.NonExistingTable  -- Table does not exist in database model
END
```

This code will raise an error.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Test
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM dbo.ExistingTable    -- Table does exist in database model
    WHERE NonExistingColumn = 0        -- but column does not exists in table
END
```

Comment: It's called deferred name resolution. It's annoying and there's still no way to force SQL Server to not do it, despite users asking for such an option for years.

Comment: Is there any reasons why SQL keep that option alive?

Comment: There's certainly a case for it not checking for *temp* table existence at creation time since it's not uncommon to want to create such a table in an outer scope before executing the procedure, but I've not personally encountered any use case when it comes to permanent tables.

Comment: Before few days, one of my friends told me one potential solution. That will be when you have created model which you must reorganize, an if you have chained SP's it's maybe more practical to allow to create them without checking their existence in model. Later you will surely correct all SP's to work properly. It has little sense for me to allow creating SP's with deferred name resolution

Comment: This link will help: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190686(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: It's OK explanation, but still I cannot find distinction between table and, let's say, column or other object. Why it is allowed only for table. I'm sure there is appropriate reason for that.

Comment: I can't seem to access it at the moment, but here's a [connect suggestion](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/127152/ability-to-disable-or-workaround-deferred-name-resolution) to allow us to disable it. From 2005. 29 upvotes. No downvotes. Still active and no apparent intention to ever implement it.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the tables exist in the DB physically. So, when you try to create this procedure, it will try to see if there is a column with name 'NonExistingColumn' in table schema.

To understand it more, try to run below script.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE HELLO
AS
BEGIN

CREATE TABLE NONEXISTINGTABLE (TID INT)
SELECT * FROM NONEXISTINGTABLE WHERE NONEXISTINGCOLUMN='N'
END
```

This will not give any error because table also doesn't exist in DB. So it cannot check for existance of that column.